# cannot let another variable point to console.log

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript so my terminologies might be wrong. Since functions are just variables in javascript, why does the Chrome console complain when I do

```
var f = console.log
```

and apply

```
f(123)
```

The error log is the following.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation  
    at <anonymous>:2:1  
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:905:140)  
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:838:34)  
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

Comment: Format your questions nicely when you ask.  Use capital letters to start a sentence.  It doesn't matter if you are new to whatever your question is about. You are expected to ask decent questions - you are not new to asking questions are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/8pL5Lgd2/

```
var f = console.log;
f("!23");
```

Comment: Saying that it works isn't an answer, since you haven't told him what to do to fix his problem. I believe this is browser-dependent.